# How to: Set keyboard/text input type for entire app (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I basically want to lock the TextInputType for an entire Flutter app but can't work out how to do it.

It's using a WebView and therefore I'm not implement any of my own TextFields.

I'm not quite sure if this is possible in Flutter as I haven't found a way to do it yet

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make a global variable for an Edit Text and use it any where you want.

Like

```
Widget myTextFormField({TextEditingController controller, Function validator, String hintText, String labelText,}){
return TextFormField(
controller: controller,
validator: validator,
autofocus: false,
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
decoration: InputDecoration(
  contentPadding:
  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 15),
  hintText: hintText,
  labelText: labelText,
  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
),);}
```

You Can Use it Any where....

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I'm not implementing any of my own TextField or TextFormFields. I'm using a WebView and would like to restrict the keyboard that's used in that to prevent the "GIF" and "Image" functions above it.

Comment: Sorry i Understand wrong.. in hTML you can't do anything like this.. I think so.